# Some excercises on independent and identically distributed random variables

Tags: probability-theory

> Let $X_1, X_2, X_3$ be three independent and identically distributed random variables with
>
> $$P(X_1 = 0) = 1/5, P(X_1 = 1) = 4/5.$$
>
> Define
>
> $$Y_1 = max\{X_1, X_2\}, \ Y_2 = max\{X_2, X_3\}.$$
>
> Determine the distributions, the expected values and the variances of $Y_1, Y_2$ and determine $Cov(Y_1, Y_2)$.

I believe that, since $X_1, X_2$ and $X_3$ are identically distributed, we are allowed to assume that $max\{X_1, X_2\} = X_1$. Furthermore, due to their identical distribution, we have that $P_{Y_1} = P_{Y_2}$. We receive:

$$P{Y_1}(0) = P(Y_1 = 0) = P(X_1 = 0) = 1/5,$$

$$P{Y_1}(1) = P(Y_1 = 1) = P(X_1 = 1) = 4/5.$$

$X_1, X_2$ and $X_3$ are Bernoulli-distributed, hence

$$E(Y_1) = E(X_1) = 0P(X_1 = 0) + 1P(X_1 = 1) = 4/5 = E(Y_2),$$

$$Var(Y_1) = Var(X_1) = P(X_1 = 0)P(X_1 = 1) = 4/25 = Var(Y_2).$$

Last but not least, since $X_1, X_2$ and $X_3$ are independent, $Y_1$ and $Y_2 $ are independent too, hence

$$Cov(Y_1, Y_2) = 0.$$

Is that correct or did I do something wrong?

Comment: I cannot follow your belief that we can assume $\max(X_1,X_2)=X_1$ on base of iid.

Comment: Being of identical distribution does not imply that the *variables* themselves will be identical, and indeed being of *independent* distribution in fact guarantees that they need not realise the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On base of the data we find $Y_i\in\{0,1\}$ a.s. for $i=1,2$, and also that $Y_1,Y_2$ have the same distribution.

Observe that: $$Y_1=0\iff X_1=0\wedge X_2=0$$ so that:$$\Pr(Y_1=0)=\Pr(X_1=0\wedge X_2=0)=\Pr(X_1=0)\Pr(X_2=0)=\frac15\frac15=\frac1{25}$$

Then it follows that: $$\Pr(Y_1=1)=\frac{24}{25}$$

This makes us find the expectation and variance on the way you describe, but with different outcomes:$$\mathbb EY_1=\frac{24}{25}\text{ and Var}Y_1=\frac{24}{25}\frac{1}{25}=\frac{24}{625}$$

For finding $\text{Covar}(Y_1,Y_2)$  we can use the well known equality:$$\text{Covar}(Y_1,Y_2)=\mathbb EY_1Y_2-\mathbb EY_1\mathbb EY_2$$

The expectations $\mathbb EY_i$ are found above, so it remains to find $\mathbb EY_1Y_2$.

I will leave that up to you (give me a signal if you get stuck), and by this realize that $Y_1Y_2$ also takes values in $\{0,1\}$ a.s..

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I would say, if $Y_1Y_2 = 1$, then $Cov(Y_1, Y_2) = E(1) - 24^2/625 = 1 - 24^2/625$, and if $Y_1Y_2 = 0$, then $Cov(Y_1, Y_2) = E(0) - 24^2/625 = 0 - 24^2/625$.

Comment: The covariance of $Y_1,Y_2)$ is a real number. It depends on the common **distribution** of $Y_1,Y_2$ and not on the outcomes of the random variables $Y_1,Y_2$ (as you seem to think). Can you find $\mathbb EY_1Y_2$? Note that $\mathbb EY_1Y_2=\Pr(Y_1Y_2=1)$ since $Y_1Y_2$ takes values in $\{0,1\}$ a.s.

Comment: So $P(Y_1Y_2 = 1) = P(Y_1 = 1, Y_2 = 1) = P(Y_1 = 1) P(Y_2 = 1) = 24/25 * 24/25 = 24^2 / 25^2$. Hence, $Cov(Y_1, Y_2) = 24^2/25^2 - 24^2/25^2 = 0$.

Comment: Why do you think that $\Pr(Y_1=1,Y_2=1)=\Pr(Y_1=1)\Pr(Y_2=1)$?

Comment: Okay, you're right, that's not correct. So I'd better start off with $P(Y_1 = 1, Y_2 = 1) = P(X_1 = 1 \ or \ X_2 = 1, X_2 = 1 \ or \ X_3 = 1)$?

Comment: I would go for finding $\Pr(Y_1Y_2=0)=\Pr(X_2=0\wedge\min(X_1,X_3)=0)=\Pr(X_2=0)\Pr(\min(X_1,X_3)=0)=\Pr(X_2=0)(1-\Pr(\min(X_1,X_3)=1)=\Pr(X_2=0)(1-\Pr(X_1=1)\Pr(X_3=1))$.

Comment: This followed by $\Pr(Y_1Y_2=1)=1-\Pr(Y_1Y_2=0)$

Comment: Ah, well, the rest is self explanatory then. :-) Thank you very much for your effort and patience!

Answer (score 1):

$\def\P{\operatorname{\mathsf P}}\def\E{\operatorname{\mathsf E}}\def\Cov{\operatorname{\mathsf {Cov}}}$No.   Two random variables being of identical and independent distribution does *not* mean that their maximum will have the same distribution.   Why would it?

In fact we have, $\P(Y_1=0)~=~\P(\max\{X_1,X_2\}=0) ~=~ \P(X_1=0 \cap X_2=0)~=~1/25\\ \P(Y_1=1)~=~\P(\max\{X_1,X_2)=1)~=~\P(X_1=1\cup X_2=1)~=~24/25\\\E(Y_1) ~=~\E(\max\{X_1,X_2\})~=~24/25 $

And so forth.

Use similar argument to find the joint probabilities, and mainly $\P(Y_1=1, Y_2=1)$, to evaluate $$\Cov(Y_1,Y_2)= \E(\max\{X_1,X_2\}\max\{X_2,X_3\})-\E(\max\{X_1,X_2\})\E(\max\{X_2,X_3\})$$